# Knex.JS Auto Update Trigger

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I am using [Knex.JS](http://knexjs.org/) migration tools. However, when creating a table, I'd like to have a column named `updated_at` that is automatically updated when a record is updated in the database.

For example, here is a table:

```
knex.schema.createTable('table_name', function(table) {
    table.increments();
    table.string('name');
    table.timestamp("created_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp("updated_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp("deleted_at");
})
```

The `created_at` and `updated_at` column defaults to the time the record is created, which is fine. But, when that record is updated, I'd like the `updated_at` column to show the new time that it was updated at automatically.

I'd prefer not to write in raw postgres.

Thanks!

Answer (score 87):

With Postgres, you'll need a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html). Here's a method I've used successfully.

### Add a function

If you have multiple migration files in a set order, you might need to artificially change the datestamp in the filename to get this to run first (or just add it to your first migration file). If you can't roll back, you might need to do this step manually via `psql`. However, for new projects:

```
const ON_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP_FUNCTION = `
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_update_timestamp()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    NEW.updated_at = now();
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
`

const DROP_ON_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP_FUNCTION = `DROP FUNCTION on_update_timestamp`

exports.up = knex => knex.raw(ON_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP_FUNCTION)
exports.down = knex => knex.raw(DROP_ON_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP_FUNCTION)
```

Now the function should be available to all subsequent migrations.

### Define a `knex.raw` trigger helper

I find it more expressive not to repeat large chunks of SQL in migration files if I can avoid it. I've used `knexfile.js` here but if you don't like to complicate that, you could define it wherever.

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    // ...
  },

  production: {
    // ...
  },

  onUpdateTrigger: table => `
    CREATE TRIGGER ${table}_updated_at
    BEFORE UPDATE ON ${table}
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_update_timestamp();
  `
}
```

### Use the helper

Finally, we can fairly conveniently define auto-updating triggers:

```
const { onUpdateTrigger } = require('../knexfile')

exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable('posts', t => {
    t.increments()
    t.string('title')
    t.string('body')
    t.timestamps(true, true)
  })
    .then(() => knex.raw(onUpdateTrigger('posts')))

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable('posts')
```

Note that dropping the table is enough to get rid of the trigger: we don't need an explicit `DROP TRIGGER`.

This all might seem like a lot of work, but it's pretty "set-and-forget" once you've done it and handy if you want to avoid using an ORM.

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: Not only does it work, great example on how to add functions to postgres. Thanks!

Comment: This is a fantastic solution and boy is it clean. Thanks, Rich!

Comment: Excellent answer. Is it required to write method `onUpdateTrigger ` on knexfile?

Comment: No, it essentially just returns a string so you could put it anywhere you like. I just find it easier to store such things with (or near) `knexfile.js`.

Comment: Why do you need to to change the time stamp or put it in the first migration, is this just so you can use it in subsequent migrations? If you only want to use it in future migrations would it be fine to have it within a migration sequence, or is there something specific about it that means it goes first?

Comment: Yes, it's so the function exists when you go to use it in subsequent migrations. If you don't need it for tables that already exist in your schema, there would be no need to worry about this.

Comment: Great solution! I added `WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)` to my `onUpdateTrigger` to prevent updates from triggering when nothing actually changed. This example is taken from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Oh good call. I wrote this years ago, when I barely knew what `NEW` was! I'll update.

Comment: Working with knex 2.x, for multiple tables you chain `then`....
    .then(() => knex.raw(knexfile.default.onUpdateTrigger('users'))
        .then(() => knex.raw(knexfile.default.onUpdateTrigger('invoices'))

Answer (score 20):

You can create a knex migration using [timestamps](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-timestamps):

```
exports.up = (knex, Promise) => {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.createTable('table_name', (table) => {
      table.increments();
      table.string('name');
      table.timestamps(false, true);
      table.timestamp('deleted_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    })
  ]);
};

exports.down = (knex, Promise) => {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('table_name')
  ]);
};
```

With [timestamps](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-timestamps) a database schema will be created which adds a `created_at` and `updated_at` column, each containing an initial timestamp.

To keep the `updated_at` column current, you'll need `knex.raw`:

```
table.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

To skip the `knex.raw` solution, I suggest using a high level ORM like [Objection.js](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/). With [Objection.js](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) you could implement your own `BaseModel` which then updates the `updated_at` column:

**Something.js**

```
const BaseModel = require('./BaseModel');

class Something extends BaseModel {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static get tableName() {
    return 'table_name';
  }
}

module.exports = Something;
```

**BaseModel**

```
const knexfile = require('../../knexfile');
const knex = require('knex')(knexfile.development);
const Model = require('objection').Model;

class BaseModel extends Model {
  $beforeUpdate() {
    this.updated_at = knex.fn.now();
  }
}

module.exports = BaseModel;
```

Source: http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#timestamps

Comment: Upvote for Objection.js. Really nice ORM for node.js

Comment: Probably a bit late to the party, but shouldn't the line of the first script: `table.timestamp('deleted_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());` read `table.timestamp('deleted_at').defaultTo(null);` instead? As it stands, you seem to be setting the `deleted_at` to current timestamp by default.

Answer (score 4):

This is my way of doing that in Mysql 5.6+

The reason I didn't use table.timestamps is because I use DATETIME instead of timestamp.

```
table.dateTime('created_on')
        .notNullable()
        .defaultTo(knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))

table.dateTime('updated_on')
        .notNullable()
        .defaultTo(knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```

Comment: This is the best and the easiest workaround. Knex has `table.timestamps(true, true)`, but it doesn't work as expected, i.e. for update.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of Knex. Knex only creates the columns, but does not keep them up to date for you.

If you use, the Bookshelf ORM, however, you can specify that a table has timestamps, and it will set & update the columns as expected:

- [Bookshelf docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-hasTimestamps)
- [Github issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/305)

Answer (score 0):

exports.up = (knex) => {
return knex.raw(`create or replace function  table_name_update() RETURNS trigger AS $$ begin new.updated_at = now(); RETURN NEW; end; $$ language 'plpgsql'; create or replace trigger tg_table_name_update on table_name  before update for each row execute table_name_update();`)
};

exports.down = (knex) => {
return knex.raw(`drop table if exists table_name; drop function if exists table_name_update;`)
};

Comment: This is the content of the migration file. Sorry for the format. I am on mobile.

Answer (score -4):

You can directly use this function

```
table.timestamps()
```

This will create the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' columns by default and update them accordingly

https://knexjs.org/#Schema-timestamps

Comment: `table.timestamps()` needs to be turned into `table.timestamps(false, true);` to guarantee that the current timestamp is used when no data is given.

Comment: Even if `table.timestamps(false, true);` is used, it does not update the `updated_at` column.