# knex how to auto update column value?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

mysql

```sql
`modify_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'modify datetime'
```

javascript

```js
knex.schema.createTable(`record_${today}`,
    function (table) {
        table
            .datetime("modify_at")
            .comment("modify date")
            .notNullable()
            .onUpdate(knex.fn.now());
    }
);
```

the code run error. it say onUpdate is not a function

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106302/122643) gives a MySQL approach (using `.raw`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this porpoise, you can use timestamps method http://knexjs.org/#Schema-timestamps

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not achieve the result suggested by the SQL in the question (it only sets the timestamp values once, not on each update).

Comment: This is wrong answer. Rich Churcher gave link to correct in his other comment.